# Customise the facebook login and logout button

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook SDK: Replace “Log In” button with custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952611/facebook-sdk-replace-log-in-button-with-custom-image)

I have this:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

How do I customize the button by it image, size and etc?

Comment: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_Login_Buttons

Answer (score 4):

if you're using new Facebook JavaScript SDK you can use any element as button - just attach onclick event to that element and invoke [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) with necessary parameters.

Comment: William is asking about the appearance, not the interaction or events.

Comment: @EricH He addressed this in saying that you can use "any element as a button", meaning you can style the element as you wish, then simply bind the onclick event.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) (if you are new, check the [example given](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)), you can get the URL to redirect the user to the Facebook login page with :

```
$fb_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

You can then include it in your page as a normal link :

```
<a href="<?php echo $fb_login_url ?>" id="facebook_login_link">
  Login with Facebook
</a>
```

that you can customize with some CSS, for example :

```
#facebook_login_link {
  background: url(my_button_image.png) no-repeat top left;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

William,

This link may shed some light on what you are trying to accomplish: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/09/implementing-facebook-login-part-3/

The above blog post has a rundown of some optional attributes:

- **condition**
  string Indicates whether the button is visible or hidden.
- **size**
  string Specifies the size of the button. Specify icon to display a favicon only, or small, medium, large, or xlarge. (Default value is medium.)
- **autologoutlink**
  bool If true and the user is already connected and has a session, then the button image changes to indicate the user can log out. Clicking the button logs the user out of Facebook and all connected sessions. (Default value is false.)
- **background**
  string Specifies the button image to use that is anti-aliased to match the background of your site — whether it’s pure white, light, or dark. Specify white, dark, or light. (Default value is light.) Note: You don’t specify this attribute if you are using v=”2″.
- **length**
  string Specifies which text label to use on a button with size specified as small, medium, large, or xlarge. Specify short for the text label Connect only or long for the text label Connect with Facebook. If you are rendering the login button text by including it within the fb:login-button tags, you don’t specify a length at all. (Default value is short.)
- **onlogin**
  string JavaScript code to execute when the user gains a Facebook session (that is, after logging into Facebook and authorizing the site).
- **v**
  string Specify “2″ to use the latest Facebook Connect login buttons, (examples available in the Facebook Connect wizard). Don’t use the attribute if you need to use the original Facebook Connect login buttons.

Comment: Do you really think that he haven't solved his issue for about year?! ;-)

Comment: I googled and found this page.  I don't particularly care if he has solved it or not.  Anyone else who googles for a similar problem could be helped by this.  Don't sell stackoverflow short by thinking it only helps the person asking the question ;-)

Comment: oh, really good point, +1 to that. But anyway I think that custom element with custom js provides more flexibility, than xfbml

Comment: Yea I definitely agree with you on that.  I ended up doing exactly that in my implementation.  The XFBML button is too black box :/

Answer (score 1):

Head over to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image/9811496#9811496), I have already explained this and also provided the code. Let me know if it still needs further clarification.

Here is a shorter version of that code -

HTML PART -

```
<a href="#" onclick="fb_login();"><img src="images/fb_login_awesome.jpg" border="0" alt=""></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION -

```
function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            //console.log(response); // dump complete info
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                user_email = response.email; //get user email
          // you can store this data into your database             
            });

        } else {
            //user hit cancel button
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

        }
    }, {
        scope: 'publish_stream,email'
    });
}
```