# Facebook SDK: Replace "Log In" button with custom image

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

I have Page Tab App, which has a landing page with a "Log In" button for users to click to install the App. Can I replace the "Log In" button with my custom image?

The current code for the "Log In" button is :

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="friend_likes"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810335/how-to-change-facebook-login-button-with-my-custom-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JS Api for this,

```
function fbAuth() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('User fully authorize the app.');
      } else {
        alert('User canceled login or did not fully authorize the app.');
      }
    }, { scope: 'friend_likes' });
}
```

then you can call it in a custom button with the onclick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return fbAuth();">Login</a>
```

Facebook Documentation: [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)